# Global click event listener in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt site with external links scattered around various pages and components:

```js
<b-link :href="http://example.com" class="external"></b-link>
```

Suppose I have a function that tells my API when an external link is clicked and records some data about it:

```js
async logExternalClick(el) {
  await this.$axios.post('http://api.example.com', {
    current_user_id: this.$store.state.auth.user_id,
    url: el.href
  }
}
```

(This method is very fast and effectively returns immediately.)

If this was just a single component, I could add the function to the `methods` section (where it was access to the store) and use `@click` handlers on all the links.

From an architecture standpoint, how should I register my function and event listener so that it's available everywhere without having to modify every component where I want to use it?

Comment: `Vue.mixin({mounted: registerInMountedEverytime})`

Comment: You can also use [nuxt-global-base-components](https://github.com/DaxChen/nuxt-global-base-components)

Comment: I registered a mixin as a global plugin in my nuxt.config.js and that seems to work well.